# please how can I get my view to display content in laravel

Tags: laravel

this is my route

```
Route::post('/registerLandLord', 'RegisterLandLordController@register');
```

this is my controller

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use DB;
 use Storage;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
 use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

 class RegisterLandLordController extends BaseController
 {
    //use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        return view('registrationSuccessfull');
    }
 }
```

this is my registrationSuccessfull view

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Real Estate Management System</title>
    <base href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/">

    <link href="/CSS/interface.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min(first).js" type='text/JavaScript'> 
    </script>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="nav">
           <button>Home</button>
      </div>
      <div>
          <div class="continueButton">
            <button>Continue</button>
          </div>
          <p></p>
      </div>
<script type="text/JavaScript">  
     console.log('tunji');
</script>
</body>
```

however the page returned by laravel is a blank document. please guys how do I fix this.
How do I get the content to start showing! 
have tried the following
'php artisan view:clear'

Comment: Your Route seems to for a `Route::post` you probably need  `Route::get` if you want to return a view.

Comment: let me try this now

Comment: replacing it with a get method is returning method not allowed

Comment: so what can I do next

Comment: Unsure, you are hitting a controller that looks like its named to Register a landlord, but you are trying to load a view that says the registration is successful, if you are getting a method not allowed after changing it to get then it means your probably posting to that controller some data from a form but your contoller isn't doing anything with that data and just trying to return a view. Usually you would save the posted data and redirect to a success page.

Comment: I just posted only the part of the code that is relevant

Comment: the view being returned is a blank page which is not suppose to be

Comment: way forward please

Comment: Is your browser getting a 200 response code?

Comment: yes my browser is getting a 200 response code

Comment: being on this issue now for 24hours

Comment: Returning a view from a POST request is not a pattern I use or see. however it may work just fine. However if I were you I would create a RegisterLandLordSuccessController and Route with a single function of loading your success view and redirect to the new success view after saving your landlord.

Comment: would try out that solution then

Comment: still wondering why I should use a get method to submit a form rather than a post method

Comment: You shouldn't i made that mistake because you had omitted the code that processes the form and then tried to load a view with a blade template a pattern have not seen. However your form should be submitted to a POST route and redirect to a GET success page

Comment: would definitely do this now